# Mysql mapping two table

Tags: mysql, database

How to mapping two table ?

table tableA:

```
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field            | Type                  | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| id               | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment                |
| name             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                |                               |
| price            | decimal(8,2) | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+

+------+------------+
| id | name | price |
+------+------------+
12 | foo   |    0.12 |
2 | barr   |    0.20 |
+------+------------+
```

table tableB:

```
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field      | Type                  | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| id         | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment                |
| user_id    | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| service_id | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| price      | decimal(8,2) | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+


+------------+------------+
| user_id | service_id | price |
+------------+------------+
| 2       |          12 |  0.01 |
+------------+------------+
```

When query to get of user mapping. Also like "SELECT price FROM tableA" need returns tableB column value.

Example of result:

```
+------+------------+
| id | name | price |
+------+------------+
12 | foo   |    0.01 |
+------+------------+
```

Comment: what's your expect result ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include details about what kind of mapping you want to do, how the tables are supposed to be used together, what you want to put IN to your query (parameters) and what results you want to get OUT (from) your query.  Give us a description and some sample IN and OUT values.

Comment: What do mean by Mapping?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

What do you really mean by mapping two tables? There are three main mapping methods.

- Insert
- Update
- Delete
  I think you can get more idea of visiting these sites.
- (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/compare-two-tables-to-find-unmatched-records-mysql.aspx)
- (https://help.10web.io/hc/en-us/articles/360016083011-Settings-MySQL-Mapping)

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you have commented.

Answer (score 1):

Based on "Example Result" you are trying to link `TableA` with `TableB` with `id` and `service_id`. In that case, you can achieve the result by running this query

```
Select ta.id,ta.name,tb.price 
from TableA ta,TableB tb Where
ta.id = tb.service_id;
```

The above query provides the relation for the tables.